# Network manager forgets static ip setting upon restart

Tags: network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 Desktop version, and I have an ethernet connection between my PC and a printer. There seems to be multiple issues with Network Manager such as:

1. When I specify a static IP address for my computer, it doesn't take effect immediately
2. The biggest problem is even though I managed to set a static ip address on my computer to communicate with my printer, upon a reboot, I lost all my static settings.

I have googled a bit on this problem which seems to be well known, but I am not sure by reading other's post what solution is to this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to have a static IP address for the printer and a seperate DHCP address to reach the internet? I doubt that NM is designed to do that. Is the printer connected to the router or free-standing and available only by wireless?

Comment: Yes. The printer is connected directly to the computer with ethernet cable. The printer has IP 192.168.123.100 and I need to configure my computer with IP 192.168.123.101 for them to communicate over ethernet cable. Then the computer is connected to the router wirelessly for Internet access. There it gets an internal IP address asigned by the router with DHCP.

Comment: Is it possible to conect the printer by ethernet to the router? If so, the method is quite straightforward and persistent.

Comment: I am afraid this this no possible currently due to the location of router and the printer device.